# How to prevent typing some characters into a field?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a date of birth field. How can I prevent a user from typing anything **except** from numbers and forward slashes (/)?

Below is code to better explain the issue.

```
    if(/*the user types anything that is not a forward slash or number*/){
    //remove it
    }
```

I have tried regex, it works for some inputs but if I type something like equals to (=) it still submits the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!isNaN(rec) check that char is Number or not and also we check does rec is equal to '/'  or not. If one of these conditions are satisfied, then we return rec

```
const str = '124sfsd325//24t#%$'

const date = str.split('').filter(rec => {
  if (!isNaN(rec) || rec === '/') {
    return rec
  }
}).join('')
```

If you want to make this solution more flexible create array of symbols

```
const str = '124sfsd325//24t#%$'
const arrayOfSymbols = ['/', '#']

const date = str.split('').filter(rec => {
  if (!isNaN(rec) || arrayOfSymbols.includes(rec)) {
    return rec
  }
}).join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use HTML `input type="date"` to not bother with the users input.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: i am already using a plugin for the date, i find <input id="date" type="date"> a longer way for users to pick dates because they have to go through every month, for someone who is 30 years old they will have to go through like 360 months to get to their date of birth

Comment: @lldana or is there a way to style it

Answer (score 1):

Use this for dates.

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

Comment: i am already using a plugin for the date, i find <input id="date" type="date"> a longer way for users to pick dates because they have to go through every month, for someone who is 30 years old they will have to go through like 360 months to get to their date of birth

Comment: or is there a way to style it